# Magento 2.3.5p1 Blank Tab Issue in Configuration Screens

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have a fresh install of Magento 2.3.5p1 running.  Passed all requirements for  set up, running PHP73 , MySQL 56 and so on and everything looks fine until you go to Stores > Configuration.

Under the General > General Tab, I have a blank area and the same for Sales > Shipping Settings, Sales > Shipping Methods, Sales > Payment Methods, Sales Tax

This is what the screen looks like for reference

[image]

I have tried compile, static:content deploy, reindexing, cache flushing and everything else I can think of.

I also have version 2.3.3 running on exactly the same site (using different directories and database of coure) and it runs perfectly, but from v2.3.4 I've had this issue with tabs being blank, and can't figure it out.

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: Honestly, if I knew what the issue was, I would have half the battle won I expect.  I literally have no idea what the problem is, hence asking the question.

Comment: Sorry, are you asking about programming? Or is this Magento in general?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the issue myself in the end.
The most frustrating thing about this was that it wasn't throwing any errors anywhere, until I tried to visit the products page which generated and error report containing the error;

Warning: Magento\Framework\Locale\TranslatedLists::getCountryTranslation(): Cannot load resource element 'XK'

So, to fix the issue (probably not a great fix for everyone but certainly ok for scenario), was to go to the directory_country table in the database and delete the 'XK' row, now everything has returned and works perfectly.  Hope this helps someone else suffering with the same issue.